# Using Xcode 6 on 10.9 no iOS 8.0 simulator available

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

I've also installed on a 10.10 partition and have access to the iOS 8.0 simulators there, but for some reason when following the same setup process on 10.9 no 8.0 simulators are available, I only have the option to use 'iOS Device'.

My command line tools are the latest ones for Mavericks and selected under 'locations'. If I change my deployment target I can launch a 7.1 simulator. The only potential outlier is that I use iRamDisk to manage simulator and derived data file storage. However, I've disabled this, uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode to no avail. Could other Xcode installations be conflicting?

Any help or ideas are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I met this problem, when reinstalled the Xcode 6 from Beta 6 to Beta 7

Comment: Please check:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/25388857

This worked for me..Thanks

Comment: As mentioned by @jeremy, this problem is triggered when you rename the Xcode app after initially launching it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I had the same problem after restoring from Time Machine on a new MacBook Pro and found the [solution](https://devforums.apple.com/message/977451#977451) from Abel Pascual in the Developer Forums:

1. Open Xcode 6 beta
2. Go to the menu Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator
3. Even if an error dialog shows up, you still would have access to the iOS Simulator's menu
4. Select Hardware > Device > Manage Devices
5. Add (if missing) all the devices that you want, or delete and recreate the ones malfunctioning.

(You can check the devices at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`).

Comment: Thanks @Binks! That was indeed the answer, I also did a restore from Time Machine, that may very well be the catalyst.

Comment: @NextRiot the correct answer is from amleszk answered Aug 27 at 20:46

Comment: crazy thing for me is that ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices doesn't exist. I also restored from a backup - Crashplan in my case. I'll try an Xcode reinstall again and see how it goes...

Comment: It seems like iOS Simulator > Hardware Menu > Device > Manage Devices goes to the same place as Xcode > Window Menu > Devices ?

Comment: @Ryan Yes it does. Also this just worked for Xcode 7 Beta. Thank you for pointing that out (I couldn't get the iOS Simulator menu to appear with the popup).

Comment: It's been a while, so I don't exactly remember, but I believe a fresh install of Xcode did the trick for me. The restore from Crashplan just wasn't quite enough as I recall.

Answer (score 115):

The accepted answer did not work for me, restarting OSX fixed the issue

Comment: I had this issue after installing Xcode 6.0.1. Restarting the computer solved it.

Comment: I am glad that it helped to get rid of the issue. However, not happy about restarting on Mac OS X :)

Comment: @nextRiot check this answer

Comment: Apple is becoming the new Microsoft :(

Comment: restarting osx did NOT fix the issue for me, the accepted answer did

Comment: @FedeCugliandolo this didn't fix the issue for me. The answer I selected did. I initially tried restarting when this issue first arose, to no avail. And being that my selected answer has a healthy amount of upvotes, I'm going to keep it as is until this answer grossly outweighs the other. A difference of ~30 votes isn't a large enough lead for me to consider it a gross outweighing.

Answer (score 10):

This Worked for me..Try changing **Deployment Target**

[image]

Comment: Swish! You're a hero.

Comment: My target was on iOS9.1 and then I changed it to iOS9 and it worked. #Hero

Comment: Yep - this worked for me. Restart OSX and the other answers above didn't. I think it was because I had been running the beta version (7.0) of Xcode and OS 9 had been selected. When I switched to the normal version of Xcode, OS 9 was still selected but greyed out. Dropping back to 8.4 sorted it.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the Xcode 6 release notes, you will not be able to use the iOS Simulator if you rename Xcode.app after launching it.  Currently, the workaround is to just rename it back or reboot.

This issue should be mostly resolved with Xcode 7.  There are still a few edge cases, but most users should not experience problems like this any more.

Answer (score 5):

There are different solution to this problem :

1. Download simulators for Xcode
   **Xcode -> Preference -> Downloads**

   Here, you can download simulators available in **'Components'** tab.
   Also, download the **'Library'** available in Documentation tab. This might be useful help.

[image: Screenshot]

2. After downloading if iOS 8 simulator doesn't appears then **reboot your Mac**.

Step 1 and 2 helped me in fixing issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely not the answer anyone here is looking for, but in my build settings the "Supported Platform" was set to `iphoneos` instead of `iOS`; when I switched it to `iOS` it decided that it could run on the Simulators.

However, this also created like 200 errors in my project, so I'm not sure if it's the solution.