# The runtime for selected device is not installed error

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to run application using xcode 6 on ios8 simulator but I am getting error `"The runtime for selected device is not installed ".`

I have set the command line tool in preferences but no luck.
Please help.[image]

Comment: is that appear you device from schema pop-up?

Comment: @NitinGohel: Dindn't get you.

Comment: The error appears when I try to run the project on simulator iPhone4s ios8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed xode 5 back to xcode.app and it worked. iOS simulator will not run if we rename the xcode.

Answer (score 22):

This just happened to me right after a beta update to Yosemite 10.10 and Xcode 6.6. I still have XCode 5 installed, and I thought it may have been from deleting XCode 6.5, but putting it back in Applications did not help.

First, make sure you have all devices installed in your Simulator. This could fix it right off the bat.
*iOS Simulator --> Hardware --> Device --> Manage Devices*

I had all the correct devices installed, however, and was still getting the error. This is what finally fixed it:
*XCode --> Open Developer Tool --> iOS Simulator*
*iOS Simulator --> Reset Content and Settings*
*Restart computer*

Comment: For those that find this, that final reboot is essential.  When you start Xcode again, all the simulators will be back.  What happened is, as far as I can tell, Apple moved the simulator binaries in b6 and broke all the simulators.  So remove them, reboot, and they'll be back in the right places.

Answer (score 3):

After installing Xcode, be sure you "select" it in Terminal, before launching / downloading updates.

ex.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Also handy to have around...  This command shows your currently selected Xcode version.

```
sudo xcode-select --print-path
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you removed Xcode 5 from your computer.

Comment: I have xcode5 on my system. I just renamed it? This is the reason for that?

Comment: I renamed xode 5 back to xcode.app and it worked. Thanks. Please update your answer. I would like to accept it.

Comment: See also release notes: "Renaming Xcode.app after running any of the Xcode tools in that bundle may cause the iOS 
simulator to be no longer available. (16646772)  Workaround: Rename Xcode.app back to what it was when first launched or reboot your Mac." (http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_6_gl2i5q/xcode_6__beta_6_release_notes.pdf).

Comment: Fixed my problem, Moved Xcode6 beta5 back to the applications folder from trash, and it solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Xcode 6 release notes, you will not be able to use the iOs Simulator if you rename Xcode.app after launching it. Currently, the workaround is to just rename it back or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

For me restoring xCode 6 beta 5 helped