# Runtime for selected device error in playground

Tags: ios, swift-playground

I am working in the Playground. I accidentally was using OSX playgrounds instead of iOS Playgrounds, so I opened a new Playground for iOS. When I opened the Playground I immediately got this error:

"The runtime for the selected device is not installed."

This error pops up every time I try to type anything into the playground. This did not happen in the Playgrounds I created that were OSX.

Yes, I turned it off and back on again. :)

I see in this question:

[The runtime for selected device is not installed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423132/the-runtime-for-selected-device-is-not-installed-error)

that other people are having a similar issue when they are trying to run the simulator.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and is able to provide some insight into this? Thank you!

Comment: @BryanChen It's not our job to enforce NDAs, it's our job to solve problems. You aren't obliged to answer the question, but you certainly shouldn't try to hinder others that might want to. Anyway, [Apple has seriously downsized](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/) their NDA.

Comment: @BryanChen, I don't think it is a bug. I am not aware of anyone else having this problem with Playgrounds. I believe I have done something incorrectly and I would like to figure out what it is.

Comment: @Bryan It's not a dupe. From [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423132/the-runtime-for-selected-device-is-not-installed-error#comment37786473_24423132), the author of that question is trying to run an actual *project*, not a playground.

Answer (score 1):

"Bare" playground files are not working very well. Here's a workaround:

Make a new iOS project from one of the templates, and build it. Now add a new file to that project and make it an iOS playground. Now the playground will work.