# Cannot use SpriteKit in Xcode 6 Playground

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, swift-playground

I am trying to use SpriteKit in Xcode 6 playground like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground

var spriteView = SKView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1334, 650))
spriteView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.167, green: 0.165, blue: 0.164, alpha: 1.0) 
let rootScene = SKScene()

let rect = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100))

rect.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()

rootScene.addChild(rect)

spriteView.presentScene(rootScene)

XCPShowView("The Sprite View", spriteView)
```

But when I see Timeline I just see:

[image: Xcode Playground]

Can Anyone Help Me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the iOS playgrounds doesn't play well at all with SpriteKit. I got mixed results running the playground in full simulator:

[image: Full Simulator screenshot]

And works reasonably under OSX using a previous created .sks in the "Resources" folder of the playground (just like the [Balloons example](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=9))

Found this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24481462/955845) too.

Comment: Running on Full Simulator seems to have been removed in Xcode 7.1 beta 3.